# how to use FTP File Upload in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, file-upload, ftp

I would like to use `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` in my JSF application. How client side (Web Browser) upload to my web application server for large file. Even if I use `RichFaces File Upload` or `PrimeFaces File Upload`, client browser can use `HTTP Protocol`. How can I support `FTP Protocol` to client browser? Could you provide the better way?

**Cause :** the application user cannot direct access to our `Repository Server(SVN)`. Firstly, they have to upload the files to our application on `Web AS`. And then, the application `checkin/chekout` to `RepositoryServer`. The application user can upload the file which has 500M to 2G at least. That's why, I am thinking, how can I support `FTP Protocol` to browser client' to be faster. Otherwise, am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use the RichFaces File Upload or PrimeFaces File Upload for uploading big files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to send a file to a FTP server, you obviously need a FTP client.

However, a webbrowser is a HTTP client, not a FTP client. This is a natural functional design limitation of the webbrowser. JSF look like a magician, but here it really can't do anything for you. It intercepts on HTTP requests/responses only.

Indeed, you're thinking wrong. Just stick to uploading the file the usual HTTP way. If you're *absolutely positive* that you need FTP for this for some reason, then your best bet is most likely homebrewing a Java Applet for this, but this would after all be plain clumsy.

Answer (score 0):

First do HTTP upload through primefaces to a temporary directory. then through org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient or through sun.net.ftp.FtpClient upload to the required FTP Server.

Below is an example;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import sun.net.ftp.FtpClient;

/**
 *
 * @author fali
 */
public class FtpUtil {

    public String server, username,password, remote, remotedir, local;
    FtpClient ftp;
    public static int BUFFER_SIZE = 10240;
    public FtpUtil(){
        server = "localhost";
        username = "anonymous";
        password = " ";
        remotedir = "/incoming";
        remote = "dvs.txt";
        local = "C:\\dvs.txt";

    }
    protected void putFile() {
    if (local.length() == 0) {
      System.out.println("Please enter file name");
    }
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    try {
      File f = new File(local);
      int size = (int) f.length();
      System.out.println("File " + local + ": " + size + " bytes");
      System.out.println(size);
      FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(local);
      OutputStream out = ftp.put(remote);

      int counter = 0;
      while (true) {
        int bytes = in.read(buffer);
        if (bytes < 0)
          break;
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        counter += bytes;
        System.out.println(counter);
      }

      out.close();
      in.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + ex.toString());
    }
  }

    public String Upload(){
        String result="";
        try{
        ftp = new FtpClient(server);
        ftp.login(username, password);
        System.out.println(ftp.welcomeMsg);
        ftp.cd(remotedir);
        putFile();
        disconnect();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex);
            result = "Error : "+ex;
        }
        return "";
    }
    protected void disconnect() {
    if (ftp != null) {
      try {
        ftp.closeServer();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
      }
      ftp = null;
    }
  }
}
```

In your managedbean/controller;

```
public String create() {
        System.out.println("Request Button Clicked");
        try {
            // generate reference number
            //current.setReferenceno(genReferenceNo());
            // add to database 
            //getFacade().persist(current);

            // upload to ftp
            FtpUtil fu = new FtpUtil();
            fu.Upload();
            // show reference number

            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage(ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("QueueCreated"));
            JsfUtil.addSuccessMessage("Your Reference No. is :" + current.referenceno);
            current = null;
//            try {
//                System.out.println("Redirecting");
//                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().dispatch("/");
//            } catch (Exception ex) {
//                System.out.println(ex);
//            }            
            return "";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JsfUtil.addErrorMessage(e, ResourceBundle.getBundle("/Bundle").getString("PersistenceErrorOccured"));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

and some thing like this in your page;

```
<br />                    
                <ppctu:commandButton action="#{appointmentController.create}" type="Submit" value="Request" />
```

Comment: OP was asking how to upload from webpage (HTML) straight to FTP. OP wasn't asking how to upload from Java class (backing bean) to FTP. OP implies to already know that part (and, honestly, your `FtpUtil` could be done better...).

Comment: @BalusC: i understand that you are right and it was just another work around and yeah i know that the FtpUtil can be done perfect but was just a quick example.